xrdp set constant resolution, ignoring what client want
I want setup XRDP resolution, I realized the resolution is changed following RDP client expect. I tested RDP client on mobile and mtsct.exe gave different resolution.
I want XRDP resolution is constant, means I need to configure it in server side. How do I do this? I want fixed resolution 640x480. Even though RDP clients want higher resolution. They can, but it will showed as resized frame.
I'm doing this in order to reduce CPU usage, we know that higher resolution meaning higher CPU load.


Use VNC instead of RDP
First, remove XRDP
apt remove xrdp
Then do this:

apt install x11vnc xfce4 xvfb
Set desired resolution, e.g. 800x600x24 at display :0

Xvfb :0 -screen 0 800x600x24


Export the display environment:

export DISPLAY=:0


Start xfce4:

startxfce4


Start VNC server:

x11vnc -display :0

